# JSX/XML issue in WebStorm 2017.3,

Tags: webstorm

JSX seems to be acting strange. The auto-completion changes the `className` to curly braces instead of a string.

It does this:

```
className={}
```

Instead of

```
className=""
```

What can I do to remedy the situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML**, set **Add for JSX attributes** to `Quotes`

Comment: Thanks. I used `Based on type` instead. This alternates the curly braces or quotes based on the template syntax used.